# What will be the displacement of boat if two people sitting symmetrically opposite ends switch places?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames

I was solving a problem from Halliday's Fundamentals of physics, chapter $9$, question $16$:

> Ricardo, of mass $80$ kg, and Carmelita, who is lighter, are enjoying Lake Merced at dusk in a $30$ kg canoe. When the canoe is at rest in the placid water, they exchange seats, which are $3.0$ m apart and symmetrically located with respect to the canoe’s center. If the canoe moves $40$ cm horizontally relative to a pier post, what is Carmelita’s mass?

I solved it by taking the center of the canoe as the origin and got Carmelita's mass to be $76$ kg. My assumption was that center of mass must not have moved, and therefore, the sum of the product of the mass of each body w.r.t its position would be equal to the system after the switch.

However, when I looked at the solutions it's incorrect ($58$ kg is the correct answer). In the solution manual, they have listed that when Ricardo and Carmelita's switch places the center of the canoe moves by $2x$, where $x$ is the center of the mass two-person system from the middle of the canoe.

What I don't understand is why ignore the boat in calculating the center of mass of the system? I also don't understand why my approach is incorrect (or is it?). And what will be the displacement when they switch places? The solution manual has confused me very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  If you take Ricardo's original position as an origin, O, you could set up an expression for the COM, then put it equal to another similar expression after the position change and boat move, again measured from O.

These two are equal and you should get to

$$45+3m = -0.4m+33+208$$

etc...

Comment: still I don't understand what was wrong with my approach

Comment: @Hiro , you would have to show what you did.  If the COM was 0.2m to the left of the middle, with R originally at the left, you could also do a kind of 'sum of torques = 0'  with COM as origin $80\times 1.3 = 30\times 0.2+m\times 1.7$  All the best with it, you can edit to show what you did if you want

Comment: I got it! Thanks. Also in my approach I found out that I forgot to account for the change in origin as boat moves by 0.40 m

Comment: @ Hiro Great!  All the best